# Google Maps API v3 Polygon closing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon

When creating a polygon using the Google Maps API v3, how can I prevent the polygon from snapping to other 'maps'?

So instead of:
[image]

I would like to make the polygon close like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you please show us the polygon coordinates you're using?

Comment: You can reproduce the problem very easily using for example: http://the-di-lab.com/polygon But here you go:

Comment: (81, -97)(80, 93)(56, 78)(60, -94)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs when the difference between the longitudes of 2 consecutive points in the path is >=180

the longitudes of the first 2 points are -97 and 93, so that's the problem in this case(difference is 190)

The only thing I may suggest so far is to split this portion of the path:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(81, -97),
//additional point
new google.maps.LatLng(80.5, -12),
new google.maps.LatLng(80, 93),
new google.maps.LatLng(56, 78),
new google.maps.LatLng(60, -94)
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/39CtV/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/39CtV/)

Comment: So instead of 4 points, I should always use 6 in order to prevent the polygon from connecting to the other maps. Would using 8 be necessary to prevent the same behaviour at the Y axis?

Comment: Its shouldn't be nessecary for the y-axis. It's also not a matter of the number of points(splitting each portion would only work as long as you didn't want to draw a polygon that crosses the dateline).

Answer (score 0):

Once I also Needed it , and thankfully Devs had provided there Research ,so i'm sharing With you

```
//Taking Example of Bermuda Triangle

function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 5,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.886436490787712, -70.2685546875),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
};

var bermudaTriangle;

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);

// Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
var triangleCoords = [
new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737),
new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262)
];

// Construct the polygon.
bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
paths: triangleCoords,
strokeColor: '#FF0000',
strokeOpacity: 0.8,
strokeWeight: 2,
fillColor: '#FF0000',
fillOpacity: 0.35
});

bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
 }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

For More Reference

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple

Comment: This will  not help with the coordinates `(81, -97)(80, 93)(56, 78)(60, -94) `

Comment: why just as Example Cited Change The Position of method Latlng to change the Co-ordinates of your polygon path

Comment: Try it with these coordinates and see the result.