# Drawing The Shortest Line Between Points In A KML Track On Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth

UPDATE: Google fixed this bug on March 6, 2016
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8003&q=apitype%3AJavascript3%20type%3ADefect&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars

I cannot display the shortest line between two points when the shortest line crosses the international dateline.  There's an illustration of the problem at: http://cars-suck.com/Test  (Zooming in and out shows what google is up to.)

A line between San Francisco and Tokyo should cross the Pacific, since that's the shortest path.  Instead, google draws a line across North America, the Atlantic, Asia, etc.

What should I change to get the line I want?

Here's the relevant chunk of the .kml file:

```
<Placemark>
<styleUrl>#multiTrack</styleUrl>
<gx:Track>
    <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
    <when>2014-09-17T07:25:06.875-07:00</when><gx:coord>-122.4167 37.7833 0</gx:coord>
    <when>2014-09-18T12:06:42.745-07:00</when><gx:coord>139.6833 35.6833 0</gx:coord>
</gx:Track>
```

Here's the script that displays the map:

```
    <script>
  function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(21.3114, -179.9999),
      zoom: 2,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
      preserveViewport: true,
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    var kmlUrl = 'http://cars-suck.com/Test/Assets/gps_history.kml';
    loadKmlLayer(kmlUrl, map);
  }

  function loadKmlLayer(src, map) {
    var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
      suppressInfoWindows: false,
      preserveViewport: true,
      map: map
    });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

The complete .kml file is here: cars-suck.com/Test/Assets/gps_history.kml

I may have lost my mind, but I believe this worked correctly back in January.  Perhaps I was relying on something deprecated, or perhaps I simply thought it was working.

Update:  I have not lost my mind.  Someone has reported a similar problem here: productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/kQo4IcDRysk

Bug report: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8003&q=apitype%3AJavascript3%20type%3ADefect&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars

On stackoverflow: [Google Maps mangling KML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30224755/google-maps-mangling-kml)

No solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

When geometry in Google Earth needs to span across the international dateline, you have you specify the degree coordinates differently to "hint" at the intended orientation.  From the Google [KML specification](http://file:///D:/Users/212318607/Downloads/07-147r2_OGC_KML_2.2.pdf):

> Specifies the longitude of the west edge of the bounding box, in
>   decimal degrees from 0 to ±180. For overlays that overlap the meridian
>   of 180° longitude, values can extend beyond that range.

In your case, the KML would be:

```
<Placemark>
    <styleUrl>#multiTrack</styleUrl>
    <gx:Track>
        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
        <when>2014-09-17T07:25:06.875-07:00</when><gx:coord>-122.4167 37.7833 0</gx:coord>
        <when>2014-09-18T12:06:42.745-07:00</when><gx:coord>-220.3167 35.6833 0</gx:coord>
    </gx:Track>
</Placemark>
```

p.s. thanks for providing the .kml file, made this very convenient to debug!

Comment: Thanks Adam!  I would never have found that passage in the KML docs.

Making the long coord "exceed" -180 definitely gets the line headed in the correct direction, but when I used your change, as posted, look what happens when it hits the dateline: (http://cars-suck.com/Test/)

Comment: I tested my proposed method in Google Earth.  The Maps Javascript API does not actually support the full KML specification.  You can see what KML elements it supports [here](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlelementsinmaps?csw=1) and [here](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport?csw=1).  Notably missing is support for `gx:Track`.

Comment: Thanks again Adam.  I removed the gx:Track tags, using LineString instead.   Didn't change anything.  I added the results to http://cars-suck.com/Test

Comment: Looks like maps has a history of issues with geometry that crosses the 180 meridian. (See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641156/google-maps-javascript-and-working-with-polygons-crossing-180-meridian) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737394/google-maps-api-v3-polygon-closing))  You might find some workarounds in those threads, like splitting it into two lines.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the google maps javascript API.  The bug was introduced in May 2015.  [Here's the bug report](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8003&q=apitype%3AJavascript3%20type%3ADefect&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars).  Adding your vote may speed a fix.